# RStudio suddenly extremely slow (12 march 2019)

Tags: r, performance, rstudio

I ran into the super slow problem last Friday, then for 3 days it worked, and now it is back again.

At first I thought it was the internet connection, but that seems not to be the case. 
I've already tried various things such as: 
- reinstall RStudio
- Reboot PC several times
- Use a different internet network
- remove all .RData and .RHistory files that I could find

but it is still going at crawl speed.

This morning it was running as expected, a few hours later at work, same laptop, it is super slow again.

I have virtually no other programs open, and it is slow straight from the start after a reboot every single time.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to figure out what is causing this, and how to solve it?

I'm running Version 1.1.463 of RStudio on a windows 7 professional.

```
 sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] flowPeaks_1.26.0           PerformanceAnalytics_1.5.2 xts_0.11-2                 zoo_1.8-4                  gtools_3.8.1              
 [6] lemon_0.4.3                gridExtra_2.3              pryr_0.1.4                 scales_1.0.0               stringi_1.3.1             
[11] V8_2.0                     taRifx_1.0.6.1             webshot_0.5.1              broom_0.5.1                forcats_0.4.0             
[16] stringr_1.4.0              dplyr_0.8.0.1              purrr_0.3.1                readr_1.3.1                tibble_2.0.1              
[21] tidyverse_1.2.1            randomForest_4.6-14        yaml_2.2.0                 plyr_1.8.4                 colourpicker_1.0          
[26] DT_0.5                     tidyr_0.8.3                htmlwidgets_1.3            plotly_4.8.0               ggplot2_3.1.0             
[31] bit64_0.9-7                bit_1.1-14                 lubridate_1.7.4            shinyWidgets_0.4.5         shinyjqui_0.3.2           
[36] shinyjs_1.0                shinydashboard_0.7.1       shinyBS_0.61               data.table_1.12.0          shiny_1.2.0               

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.0        jsonlite_1.6      viridisLite_0.3.0 modelr_0.1.4      assertthat_0.2.0  cellranger_1.1.0  pillar_1.3.1      backports_1.1.3  
 [9] lattice_0.20-38   quadprog_1.5-5    glue_1.3.0        digest_0.6.18     promises_1.0.1    rvest_0.3.2       colorspace_1.4-0  htmltools_0.3.6  
[17] httpuv_1.4.5.1    pkgconfig_2.0.2   haven_2.1.0       xtable_1.8-3      later_0.8.0       generics_0.0.2    withr_2.1.2       lazyeval_0.2.1   
[25] cli_1.0.1         magrittr_1.5      crayon_1.3.4      readxl_1.3.0      mime_0.6          nlme_3.1-137      xml2_1.2.0        tools_3.5.2      
[33] hms_0.4.2         munsell_0.5.0     compiler_3.5.2    rlang_0.3.1       rstudioapi_0.9.0  crosstalk_1.0.0   miniUI_0.1.1.1    gtable_0.2.0     
[41] codetools_0.2-15  curl_3.3          reshape2_1.4.3    R6_2.4.0          knitr_1.22        Rcpp_1.0.0        xfun_0.5          tidyselect_0.2.5
```

Comment: memory usage is normal, around 350,000K as always

Comment: Have you cleaned your workspace?

Comment: Also, have you tried opening vanilla R and testing the performance?

Comment: yes, I've started with clear workspace/ environment. My app starts with rm(list = ls(), envir = environment())  even. I also ran  rm(list=ls()) in Rstudio directly now, no change at all

Comment: How do I run vanilla R correctly? never done that before

Comment: You should be able to search for the program by clicking the start button (I think it has the windows emblem on it), and then just type “R”, not RStudio. You should see one or two results for 32 bit and 64 bit versions of R. This is the R GUI that comes standard with every download. Click on the 64 bit version and try your test again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189880/discussion-between-mark-and-joseph-wood).

Comment: Hey Mark, the SO app doesn’t support chat yet and I have no idea what my password is. I tried replying to you, but you have to be logged in. Anywho, I read your comment and I see what you’re saying. I’m not really sure where to go with this one other than posting on the RStudio help page. I’ve never done it, but I’ve read that they are extremely helpful over there.

Comment: i will give it a try. Testing my work on a different laptop now first to see if that makes a difference

Comment: It must be the laptop. Other laptop with complete new r and rstudio install runs like clockwork

Comment: I’m glad you figured it out. That stuff can be annoying.

Comment: The question is now, how to fix my normal laptop. I'm going to try and remove all R related stuff from the disk an completely reinstall it. Packages, Rstudio, Rtools, R itself. Any things I should not forget to scrape? Adding AppData local and roaming to that delete list

Comment: I was recently having a similar issue with RStudio, particularly when using RNotebooks (crawl speed and laggy). I'm running Windows 10, but the new daily build of RStudio solved my issue. Maybe it will help you: https://dailies.rstudio.com/

Comment: The problem has returned after 4 days of working properly. I'm going nuts here

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problems in my RStudio Desktop IDE. The main problem was that it was extremely slow to start the IDE and perform trivial tasks like opening a script or using the console to perform basic calculations. Doing some research, this is what helped me:

1. [Resetting RStudio Desktop's State](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State).
2. [Running a Diagnostic Report](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200321257-Running-a-Diagnostics-Report). My issue was that my HOME environmental variable was set to a network/shared drive (i.e. OneDrive).
3. I fixed this by setting my HOME env variable to a local directory. [Check this solution.](https://gist.github.com/ateucher/f279abc1f7ba12f2763152c18810fb24) [Check this thread for more background.](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-1-1-383-issue-on-startup/1819/14)

Good luck!